# How to build freebsd kernel ?

Tags: build, makefile, kernel, freebsd

According to freeBSD handbook, we need to use the following targets to build the freeBSD kernel :-

`make KERNCONF=config_file buildkernel`

Now, even if I make a small change in a single source file, it takes a long time to compile the kernel. I am pretty sure that it is because, everything is built again including the files which were not affected in anyway.

This is creating a very big problem for me as the build time is very large (around 45 minutes) .

How can I only build the freeBSD kernel and not rebuild it ?

I have looked at the handbook and the Makefile but couldn't find any information related to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `make KERNCONF=config_file buildkernel -DNO_CLEAN`. See the [build man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=build%287%29&sektion=) for more details.

P.S. You can put `KERNCONF=config_file` in `/etc/make.conf` and `NO_CLEAN=true` in `/etc/src.conf` to avoid having to type it every time, so you don't have a chance to accidentally forget.

Answer (score 2):

If you only changed a piece of kernel source and not the kernel config, use KERNFAST.  Like this: make buildkernel KERNFAST=1.  It's so useful I've got this in my ~/.zshrc:

alias 'mbir'='make -j4 buildkernel installkernel KERNFAST=1 && reboot'

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try this . Anyway, my issue is resolved by the option -DNO_KERNELCLEAN